# mount network drives with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

i try to mount a network drives(CIFS) in Linux with Qt. But it doesnt work. Is there also another solution, without QProcess?

```
QProcess connectSamba;
    QString terminalCommand;
    terminalCommand = "mount -t cifs //" + ip + "/folder/ " + mountpath;
    connectSamba.start(terminalCommand);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather wondering if there's another solution, I think you should examine and understand why QProcess doesn't work for you.

Calling [QProcess::start](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#start-2) in this way will take the first token (mount) as the command and pass each of the following items, separated by a space, as arguments. Therefore, tokens such as "//" and "/folder/" are not valid arguments for the mount command.

You can use QProcess by doing something like this: -

```
QProcess connectSamba;

QString mountPath = "//" + ip + "/folder/ " + mountpath;
QString terminalArgs = QString("-c \"mount -t cifs %1\"").arg(mountPath);
connectSamba.start("/bin/bash", terminalArgs);
connectSamba.waitForFinished();
```

Note that the terminal arguments are surrounded by quotes to ensure that only one argument is passed and we're calling the bash interpreter with the -c argument, which takes commands from the proceeding string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me! But now I have a second problem. The read "connectSamba.readAllStandardError()" -function says, that "mount: only root can use "--types" option". -.-

Comment: As this is a different question, please can you mark this as answered and start a new one on SO; it makes it easier for others to search for the answer to the same or similar problem.